# Search page in subdirectory with extra parameter in friendly URL (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, search

My htaccess is currently

```
# rewrite engine on and setting up base
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /leffa

# replace + with _
RewriteRule ^(.+)\+(.+)$ $1-$2 [R=301]

# external redirect from action URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Which produces correct rewrite in [here](http://www.rollemaa.org/leffat) when you click on any of the movie titles. However, I have an extra parameter ?kuvauksesta=1 when you are searching from description also rather than the title (I have removed the checkbox because it currently doesn't work).

How to make this rewrite work with second parameter in search query? typing manually http://www.rollemaa.org/leffa/pelottava?kuvauksesta=1 does work, but with checkbox input it just removes the second parameter, try and see: http://www.rollemaa.org//leffa/index.php?q=pelottava&kuvauksesta=1

How to make the second parameter to say in the url so it's clean and searchable?

Comment: What should be pretty URL for `http://www.rollemaa.org//leffa/index.php?q=pelottava&kuvauksesta=1` ?

Comment: For example http://www.rollemaa.org/leffa/pelottava/kuvauksesta or anything similar that makes it to work. As long as the normal search query without the extra parameter (kuvauksesta) works like it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# rewrite engine on and setting up base
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /leffa/

# replace + with _
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\+(.+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,L,NE]

# external redirect from action URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)&(kuvauksesta)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL (extra parameter)
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ index.php?q=$1&$2=1 [L,QSA]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I noticed I have another problem. If the movie title has slash in it, the page not found. How to convert slash to something else, like dash (for example movie titled V/H/S), still retaining the rest of the rules?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Previously the movie could be found by searching http://www.rollemaa.org/leffa/index.php?q=V/H/S, so I would need slashes in the movie title to be converted to underscores or dashes in title but also so that the search page would understand them as slashes. I think I'll need some PHP for that also?

Comment: I already have it like this: https://gist.github.com/ronilaukkarinen/f056ccf335298b2f9c8e

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thank you again :)

Comment: One other guestion... if there's a dash in movie name, the rule doesn't work. Can there be an exception where dash is not considered. For example: http://www.rollemaa.org/leffa/the-amazing-spider (works), http://www.rollemaa.org/leffa/the-amazing-spider-man (doesn't work)

Comment: In my browser both URLs worked. There is no rules above that is dependent on hyphens.

Comment: Migrating my servers to nginx. Tried this http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but it doesn't seem to be working, getting redirect loop. Any help @anubhava?

Comment: Yes same Apache rules don't work on nginx. Please post a new question for `nginx to Apache` migration and you will get help from experts.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for the answer!